# Model has_many AND has_many :through in one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship, rails-models

I have a set of categories, belonging to a category set.
These categories can themselves have a mix of categories (self-referential) and also questions. 
The models and their relationships are defined & visualized as follows:

```
class CategorySet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category_set

  belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => "Category"
  has_many :categories, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_category_id", dependent: :destroy

  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

Abbrev to CS, C and Q:

CS
  |- C
     |- Q
     |
     |- C
     |
     |- C
     |  |- Q
     |
     |- C
        |- Q
        |- Q
```

I would like to be able to ask CategorySet.find(1).questions and return all questions in the tree regardless of position. The only ways I can think of use lots of function-based requests and will probably be overkill on sql statements (see below for an example).

Calling **CategorySet.find(1).categories** finds only the direct descendant categories of the category set. Also, **Category.find(id).questions** returns only the questions for that category.

I have tried overwriting the *.questions* method on categories, but that doesn't seem very rails relationship-esque and there must be a better way of doing this? Alo it means I can't do the CategorySet.includes(:questions).all style syntax which greatly reduces the load on the database server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1**

Use [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) for this

```
class CategorySet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  def questions
    categories.map do |c|   
      c.self_and_descendants.include(:questions).map(&:questions)
    end.flatten
  end
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  awesome_nested_set
  belongs_to :category_set
  has_many :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Refer to the [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) documentation to get the list of additional columns required by the gem.

**Approach 2**

The approach 1 loads all the questions in to the memory and it does not support DB based pagination.

You can get better performance if you avoid maintaining a separate table for CategorySet as each category can contain other categories.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  awesome_nested_set
  has_many :questions
  # add a boolean column called category_set

  def questions
    join_sql = self_and_descendants.select(:id).to_sql
    Question.joins("JOIN (#{join_sql}) x ON x.id = questions.id")  
  end
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  validates :category_id, :presence => true, :category_set => true
end

# lib/category_set_validator.rb
class CategorySetValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator  
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)  
    if record.category.present? and record.category.category_set?
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || 
                    "is pointing to a category set") 
    end
  end 
end
```

Now you can get questions for a category set as

```
cs.questions.limit(10).offset(0)
cs.questions.paginate(:page => params[:page])  # if you are using will_paginate
```

Comment: I apologise, it appears I gave you a deserving up vote but forgot to mark it as accepted. I implemented a solution based on the above and it worked great. Thanks!